# How to make time dependent value in firebase databse?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Is there any way to automatically update the data after a certain time.

example:-

```
  data : {
     status : active,
     validity: xxx/xxx/xx
   }
```

can we define the rules such that the `status` turns `inactive` when the current data crosses the  `validity` time?

Answer (score 0):

Technically, yes, you can use Cloud Functions to scan your database on a schedule (say, 10 seconds?) and deactive the `status`. But this is only feasible when you have only a few status to scan, because these function invocations will sky rocket once you have more data. I suggest saving the `validity` time and validate it on the frontend if you can